# How to bypass certificate validations when using generated proxy layer from asmx wsdl

Tags: c#, ssl, proxy, wsdl, asmx

I have an asmx web service that communicates with another asmx web service through the generated proxy service layer, however, due to some constraints, I need to disable certificates validation when calling the methods through the proxy layer, however, instead of disabling at the application domain level , I want to disable on request basis.

For example, I found out that on a httpwebrequest, I can do the following:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://...");
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
        (sender, cert, chain, error) =>
{
    return true;
};
```

However, in the context of the asmx web service that's using a layer of indirection to perform the HTTP calls, is there any way I can apply the the bypass of the certificates without impacting the entire app domain ? (I want to avoid using ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback)

Comment: You might be able to use some property of `sender` to identify your request so you can conditionally return `true`, without doing it for the entire app domain.

Comment: I'm in the context of an asmx web service which has a generated proxy to another asmx service. I don't find any members that would allow me to do such bypass on the validation

Comment: You cannot disable certificates if you are running https (secure using SSL/TLS encryption) because the certificate is used to encrypt the data.

Comment: @jdweng that is different than disabling validation of certificates.

Comment: Why would you want to use a certificate that had xml errors or fail the signature check?